# Can't get sound on Raspberry Pi's 3.5mm audio jack

Tags: raspbian, audio, pi-3b+, raspberry-pi-os, raspberry-pi-desktop

I've been asking this question everywhere. I've checked lot of resources, manuals, documentations out there. But couldn't get any sound out of my speaker. I tried the YouTube video tutorials also, but nothing  quite working for me. I have connected the speaker to the 3.5mm jack.

when I give `aplay-l` command I can get following dependencies:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: b1 [bcm2835 HDMI 1], device 0: bcm2835 HDMI 1 [bcm2835 HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 4/4
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
card 1: b2 [bcm2835 HDMI 2], device 0: bcm2835 HDMI 2 [bcm2835 HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 2/2
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
card 2: Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones], device 0: bcm2835 Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones]
  Subdevices: 2/2
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
card 3: Device [USB Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Card 3 is my microphone. When I give `alsamixer` command, after pressing F6, I am able to see the mic and speaker volume controls working. Even though I have configured the `sudo nano ~/.asoundrc` file as well  nothing seems happening.

When I give this command `sudo amixer cset numid=3 1` I can get the following dependencies without any error:

```
 numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Volume'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw------,values=2,min=0,max=65536,step=1
  : values=1,1
```

Help me to find a solution please.

Comment: Is your speaker amplified? It needs to be.

Comment: i think the numid you are giving is wrong, can you provide output of `sudo amixer controls`